# MongoDB does not completely write a forloop. More than 1 year error for me that was left unsolved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This has been an on-going problem for me. I have been trying to solve this since the past year. The issue is that writing a `for` loop is inconsistent. I recently added `mutex` because it is what was suggested by ChatGPT to no avail. It should always `updateRawMat` but for some reason, it didn't around 10 to 20%% of the time, that is the reason why I added to write `productionError` which made it unnecessary. What could have been causing it? My client are using mobile so sometimes internet connection stutters but for some reason they are still able to perform `updateProductionStatus` . This is my routes:

```js
router.post('/startProduction', async (req, res) => {

    const release = await mutex.acquire();

    try {

        const transactionDate = new Date();
        if (!req.body.qty || req.body.qty < 0) return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Output quantity is required' });

        const findNotUpdated = await PosProduction.findOne({ _id: req.body.mainId, status: 'Requested' }).select('status').lean();
        if (!findNotUpdated.status) return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Control Center: Production Item Not Found' });


        for (let i = 0; i < req.body.productionItems.length; i++) {

            const product = req.body.productionItems[i].product;

            const findQty = await PosBranch.findOne({ branch: req.body.branch, productName: req.body.productionItems[i].product }).select('qty sku').lean();
            if (!findQty) return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Unable to find ' + req.body.productionItems[i].product });

            const availableInventory = findQty && findQty.qty ? findQty.qty : 0;
            const sku = findQty && findQty.sku ? findQty.sku : null;
            const qtyRequirement = req.body.productionItems[i].qty * req.body.qty;
            const newQty = availableInventory - qtyRequirement;
            const fixedQty = newQty ? Math.round(newQty * Math.pow(10, 5)) / Math.pow(10, 5) : 0;

            const updateRawMat = await PosBranch.updateOne({ branch: req.body.branch, productName: req.body.productionItems[i].product }, {
                $set: { qty: fixedQty },
                $push: {
                    "production":
                    {
                        qty: qtyRequirement,
                        productionId: req.body.mainId,
                        product: req.body.product,
                        name: req.body.lastName,
                        eeid: req.body.starterEeid,
                        name: req.body.starterName,
                        lastName: req.body.starterLastName,
                        date: transactionDate,
                    }
                }
            });


            if (updateRawMat.nModified === 0) {
             
                const productionError = new posProductionError({
                    product: req.body.productionItems[i].product,
                    sku: sku,
                    branch: req.body.branch,
                    qtyRequirement: Math.round(qtyRequirement * Math.pow(10, 5)) / Math.pow(10, 5),
                    eeid: req.body.eeid,
                    firstName: req.body.starterName,
                    lastName: req.body.starterLastNamee,
                    date: transactionDate,
                    status: 'Pending',
                });
                await productionError.save();
            }


        }

        const updateProductionStatus = await PosProduction.updateOne({ _id: req.body.mainId },
            {
                $set: {
                    "status": 'Work-In-Progress',
                    "starterEeid": req.body.starterEeid,
                    "starterName": req.body.starterName,
                    "starterLastName": req.body.starterLastName,
                    "startDate": transactionDate,
                },
            });

        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Production In-Progress.' });

    } catch (err) { res.json({ success: false, message: 'Something went wrong. Try reloading' }); }
    finally { release(); }

});
```